# Android shell using busybox commands as default

Tags: android, bash, shell, stdin, busybox

I'm running a script on android and in effort to make it as portable as possible, all commands use busybox. How I've got it set up currently, is every command has a function named the same, so it converts those commands to use busybox, like so:

```
echo () {
busybox echo $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
}
echo "hai"
```

As this has to be done for every command, it takes a lot of space inside the script. That's why I'm trying to figure out a way to force the shell to default to using busybox rather than /system/bin or /system/xbin.
Could this be achieved by modifying the PATH variable? Or is there an environment variable build into shell I could use?

Or should I do something like this?:

```
bs () {
busybox $@
}

bs echo "Some text"
```

(I'd like to avoid this if possible as it decreases readability)

**EDIT**

Could I start a background process that loops and when it detects a command being passed for the shell to processes, it stops this and passes it to busybox? Somehow read from stdin before shell processes it?

**EDIT 2**

So I thought about redirecting commands into busybox like this:

```
busybox <<EOF
echo "hai";
EOF
```

Could this be used somehow?

**UPDATE**

I've moved to using busyboxes ash shell and it does everything I want it to do. Appareantly there's no way of intercepting commands before they're passed to the shell.

Comment: Can you take advantage of the fact that a symlink to `busybox` named `echo`, if executed, will execute `busybox echo`? Put all such links in a known directory, then put that directory at the front of `PATH`.

Comment: I'd rather avoid creating new symlinks as space is a limited resource. I read about busyboxes own sh applet. Apparently it's ash? Would that shell automatically call busybox over external commands? Or should I just start writing my own shell environment? :P

Comment: I think that's correct. I'm not really that familiar with busybox; I thought it was just the name of a suite of tools, rather than a command itself.

Comment: @BonBon I think that `busybox ash` _will_ in fact drop you into a shell that will call busybox functions whenever possible, falling back to binaries on the PATH if not. You could even write your script with the first line being `#!/bin/busybox ash`. When run, the whole script will be interpreted by busybox.

Comment: @savanto Yeah I just experiemented with busyboxes ash shell and it behaves similarly enough to bash, that I can use it. But I'm still wondering, is there a way of graping commands from stdin before the shell gets them? I'll edit my question tomorrow to ask that.

Comment: There is no way for another process to "intercept" a command being passed to a shell (or any program) via stdin -- that would be a grave security violation. The only thing you could do is make a wrapper, which interprets given commands and decides how to run them -- but you've already considered that in your question.

Comment: Actually (apart from the `busybox ash` method mentioned above) I don't see how you can save substantial space by not using symlinks. Symlinks are cheap, they are as long as the destination path in bytes. You can probably have symlinks for all basic commands in <1KB. Meanwhile, having function wrappers in each script might consume even more space.

Comment: So I'll consider this question as answered. I've moved to using busyboxes ash shell that does exactly what I want it to do and appareantly there's no way of intercepting commands passed to shell. Thanks for your input! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shell's built-in 'alias'  [(Alias Substitution, Shell Command Language, IEEE Standard 1003.1 (2013) )](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) method.
For example:

```
alias vi="busybox vi"
vi readme.txt
```

will substitute the word 'vi' with 'busybox vi' and the shell will then process

> busybox vi readme.txt

Because it is a simple substitution, all parameters are preserved and passed on to the substituted command.

You can also add default parameters to the substitution like so:

```
alias fbset="busybox fbset -fb /dev/graphics/fb0"
```

after which one no longer needs to specify the frame buffer - it is added for you. And typically programs will take the last specified parameter as the active one, so if you do need to specify another frame buffer (in the above example) it will ignore the one provided in the alias.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can finally mark this question as answered. In the end, I actually made a custom build of bash and busybox and added them to my installation. Now everything is ran by using one or the other and the problems is solved.

Answer (score 0):

just run all the commands from the sh included within busybox
which is configured to call all busybox utilities like sed,awk,sort,wc,...etc.

so you will just invoke:

```
$busybox sh
```

and all sub commands would be of busybox versions

and here is the reference from busybox help of running without arguments

> The shell in this build
> is configured to run built-in utilities without $PATH search.
> You don't need to install a link to busybox for each utility.
> To run external program, use full path (/sbin/ip instead of ip).